# In Mongo, how to match documents based with ranges?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents with the following attributes:

```
{
name: "Acme",
minEmployees: 11,
maxEmployees: 15,
price: 20,
priceMultiplierEmployees: 1.5
}

{
name: "Acme",
minEmployees: 0,
maxEmployees: 10,
price: 10
priceMultiplierEmployees: 1.2
}

{
name: "Acme",
minEmployees: 16
maxEmployees: 20
price: 50,
priceMultiplierEmployees: 1.6
}
```

So if one of my users inputs `minEmployees = 12` and `maxEmployees = 14`

Mongo should return the first document:

because

`11 <= 12 <= 15` and `11 <= 14 <= 15`

But I'm having problems creating that matching condition in Mongo (I'm fairly new). I've read the documentation over and over, but I keep getting results that shouldn't match some of documents.

The formula above is

`documentMinEmployees <= userInputMinEmployees <= documentMaxEmployees`
and
`documentMinEmployees <= userInputMaxEmployees <= documentMaxEmployees`

This is the current iteration of the mongo query I'm trying to use:

```
db.products.aggregate(
   [
    {
      $match: { 
        name: "Acme",
        minEmployees: {$lte: 12}
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id:  {name: "$name", price: "$price"},
        lowEndEmployees: {
          $max: "$minEmployees"
        },
        finalPrice: {
          $max: {
            $add: ["$price", {$multiply: ["$priceMultiplierEmployees", {$subtract: [12, "$minEmployees"]}]}]
          }
        }
      }
    }
   ]
);
```

The query above, right now is returning the following documents (as expected):

```
{
name: "Acme",
minEmployees: 11,
maxEmployees: 15,
price: 20,
priceMultiplierEmployees: 1.5
}

{
name: "Acme",
minEmployees: 0,
maxEmployees: 10,
price: 10
priceMultiplierEmployees: 1.2
}
```

But what I'd like it to return is only one document with the following result.

```
{
name: "Acme",
price: 20,
finalPrice: 30
}
```

Where `finalPrice` is the result of the following operation: `20 * 1.5(12 - 11)`

My main problem is that I don't know how to write this matching condition in Mongo:

`minEmployees <= userInput <= maxEmployees` **AND** `minEmployees <= userInput2 <= maxEmployees`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the final result you want as below:

```
{
    name: "Acme",
    price: 20,
    finalPrice: 30
}
```

You can use:

```
var min = 12, max = 14; 
db.products.aggregate([ {
    $match : {
        name : "Acme",
        minEmployees : {
            $lte : min
        },
        maxEmployees : {
            $gte : max
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        name : "$name",
        price : "$price",
        finalPrice : {
            $multiply : [ "$price", "$priceMultiplierEmployees", {
                $subtract : [ min, "$minEmployees" ]
            } ]
        }
    }
} ]);
```

Comment: That's exactly the result I wanted. I was trying to complicate too much my matching query. I remember my first iteration of the query looking very similarly to the one in your answer, but I had the $lte and $gte backwards. Didn't notice until today.

Comment: You will be familiar with this kind of expression (BSON) with some exercises. :)